# Values not inserted into table - Bulk insert from csv to ms-access

Tags: ms-access, bulkinsert

I am bulk inserting values from a csv file into my access table. Things were working fine,till today I encountered this problem where access inserts all the values expect for one field called BN1. It simply leaves this column balnk when the data is non numeric. This is the batch name of products and in the design the field type is memo (legacy .mdb file so cant change it).

My sample data:

```
DATE,TIME,PN1,BN1,CH0,CH1,CH2

2019-02-18,16:40:05,test,prompt,0,294,0

2019-02-18,16:40:14,test,1,700,294,0
```

So in the above data the first row is inserted with a blank value for prompt where as the 2nd row is inserted properly with BN1 as 1.

My code to insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO Log_143_temp ([DATE],[TIME],PN1,BN1,CH0,CH1,CH2
) SELECT [DATE],[TIME],PN1,BN1,CH0,CH1,CH2
 FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;DATABASE=C:\tmp].[SAMPLE_1.csv]
```

The path and the file names are correct else it wouldn't have inserted any value

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is how I solved the issue,

Changed the query to bulk insert to,

```
INSERT INTO Log_143_temp ([DATE],[TIME],PN1,BN1,CH0,CH1,CH2
) SELECT [DATE],[TIME],PN1,BN1,CH0,CH1,CH2
 FROM [Text;FMT=CSVDelimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=C:\tmp].[SAMPLE_1.csv]
```

Then add a file named schema.ini in the folder containing the csv file to be imported.

Contents of the schema.ini file,

```
[SAMPLE_1.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=CSVDelimited
DateTimeFormat=yyyy-mm-dd
Col1="DATE" Text
Col2="TIME" Text
Col3="PN1" Text
Col4="BN1" Text
Col5="CH0" Double
Col6="CH1" Double
Col7="CH2" Double
```

Now the csv files get imported without any issue.

For additional info on schema.ini visit the following link,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017